# Convert from to_char to to_date

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to convert the following format to date format(DD-MON-YYYY) BUT am unable to do so.

I have tried the following queries:-

```
 SELECT to_date(TO_CHAR (termination_date, 'DD/MON/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),'DD/MON/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
                 from term_table

o/p :6/29/2001

select trunc(termination_date) from term_table



o/p 6/29/2001



Required output is :29-JUN-2001
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming termination_date is a `DATE` column

```
SELECT to_char(termination_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
FROM term_table
```

Here's a SQLFiddle showing something similar for Oracle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35797/0

You don't need to use `TRUNC()` if your date format doesn't show any time.  (`TRUNC(datetime)` turns a datetime object with an arbitrary time of day to one at midnight.)

Answer (score 2):

use to_char to convert the date accordingly

```
SELECT to_char(termination_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
FROM term_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your required output is default output in oracle, but if you want it in mysql use this query...
**select date_format(termination_date, '%d-%b-%Y') as date from term_table;**

Comment: No, there is no default format for date in Oracle. What you say default is only `locale-specific NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. And I don't see anywhere OP mentioned any requirement for MySql.